# Sort a 1D Array from maximum to minimum

Tags: matlab

The following question is not for school / university, but rather me trying to practice some random made-up questions to better prepare for an upcoming exam.

With that said, I am currently stuck with a function that I am trying to code.

The function is supposed to take an input of an array and 'reorder' all of the elements in the array from maximum to minimum.

My approach is to use to a double for loop, to go through every element in the array, one at a time, and compare it with every element in the array.

Initially, I tried deleting every element that was already sorted. However, I started getting the following error:

```
Attempted to access array(4); index out of bounds because numel(array)=3.
Error in maxArray (line 36)
      if array(i) > array(j)
```

I then thought about possibly creating a new array where I would store all of the 'index' that have already been assigned and compare it with the 'maximum' element index and see if it has been assigned. If it has the function would ignore it and find the next best 'maximum' element to put into the new array.

However, I can't figure out how to make that work.

At the university we have not covered most of the inbuilt functions. I am aware that you can use `sort` to do the job for you. However, we are encouraged to use our own functions that we build from scratch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to implement selection sort, it sounds like. Here's a good reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/ . There are many other ways to sort, here is a long list: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/ . I suggest you try to understand the algorithms from an explanation like that, even if the code they have there is not MATLAB. Once you understand how it works, it'll be easier to translate to MATLAB.

Comment: You'll need to swap two elements in the array when sorting. This is the MATLAB syntax for swapping elements 2 and 3: `x([2,3]) = x([3,2])`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Cris Luengo for his advice. I was able to solve the question by swapping the elements in the array.

```
% Process to calculate the length of the array.
lenArray = length(array);

% If the array is empty, display an appropriate message.
if lenArray == 0
    error('The array provided is empty.')
end

% Initialise an empty array to store the two elements that are being
% compared.
compareArray = [];

% Go through every index in the new array.
for i = 1:lenArray

    % Compare each element in the array, index 'i', with every other
    % element in the array.
    for j = i+1:lenArray

        % Check to see if the current element 'j' is greater than the
        % current element 'i'.
        if array(j) > array(i)

            % Add the two elements to 'compareArray'.
            compareArray(1) = array(j);
            compareArray(2) = array(i);

            % Swap the two elements in the initial array.
            array(i) = compareArray(1);
            array(j) = compareArray(2);

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You can replace the 4 lines of code in the inner `if` statement with: `array([i,j]) = array([j,i])`. Just a nice way of expressing the swap.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, we haven't learned the statement `array([i,j]) = array([j,i])`, which is why I had to code it the long way.